# Summarize values every N columns

Tags: pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

From this dataframe :

```
|-|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| |code|M-1|M-2|M-3|M-4|M-5|M-6|M-7|M-8|
|-|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|0| DE | 3 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 9 |
|1| GT | 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 7 |
|2| KT | 8 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 3 |
|3| SZ | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
|4| NJ | 7 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
|5| DC | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|-|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
```

I would like to get that :

```
|-|----|-----|-----|
| |code| T-1 | T-2 |
|-|----|-----|-----|
|0| DE |  8  |  9  |
|1| GT |  9  |  4  |
|2| KT | 10  | 10  |
|3| SZ |  5  | 11  |
|4| NJ | 13  |  3  |
|5| DC |  4  |  9  |
|-|----|-----|-----|
```

Month-1, Month-2, Month-3 are summarized in Trimester-1.

M-4, M-5, M-6 are summarized in T-2

We lack M-9 to add the column T-3...so we deleted M-7 and M-8.

**In this example, the input dataframe goes till M-8 but it could have been just till M-1 or till M-12.**

Comment: set `code` as index, then `groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//3, axis=1).sum()`

Comment: The answer of Quand Hoang is the most direct. But : 1. It requires to import numpy. 2. he does sum also on non the full trimster "T-2.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**0. The case studied**

```
import pandas as pd

histo = {
        "article_code" : ["DE", "GT", "KT", "SZ", "NJ", "DC"],
        "M-1" : [3, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1],
        "M-2" : [0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0],
        "M-3" : [5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3],
        "M-4" : [7, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0],
        "M-5" : [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 8],
        "M-6" : [2, 3, 7, 4, 1, 1],
        "M-7" : [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "M-8" : [9, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(histo)
print(df)
```

**1. Method vectorized (using groupby)**

```
# All columns must be the months we want to group
df.set_index("article_code", inplace=True)
print(df)

# Prepare the groupby function
m_number = len(df.columns)
splitter = [x//3 for x in range(0, m_number)]
print(splitter)

# Sum per trimester
df = df.groupby(by=splitter, axis=1).sum()
print(df)

# Remove non full trimester and rename columns
t_number = m_number//3
df = df.iloc[:,:t_number]
df.columns = ["T-" + str(x + 1) for x in range(0,m_number//3)]
print(df)
```

**2. Method with a loop (using iloc)**

```
# Record the number of months 
m_number = len(df.columns) - 1

# Add sums per full trimester
for inc_t, inc_m in enumerate(range(1, (m_number//3)*3, 3)):
    df["T-" + str(inc_t + 1)] = df.iloc[:,inc_m:inc_m+3:1].sum(axis=1)
print(df)

# Delete months
df = df.iloc[:,:1].merge(right=df.iloc[:,-inc_t-1:], how="left",
                         left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: i is not a good practice to unaccept the answers and accept your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

static code may not work because as you mentioned number of columns may vary this works for any given number of columns

example input:

```
  code  M-1  M-2  M-3  M-4  M-5  M-6
0   DE    8    9   10    9   10    9
1   GT    9    4    8    4    8    4
2   KT   10   10    3   10    3   10
3   SZ    5   11    2   11    2   11
4   NJ   13    3    1    3    1    3
5   DC    4    9    0    9    0    9
```

create another dataframe df1

```
df1=df[df.columns[:1]]
for x in range(len(df.columns[1:])//3):
     df1["T-"+str(x+1)]=df[df.columns[x*3+1:(x+1)*3+1]].sum(axis=1)
df1
```

a warning might arise ignore it
output:

```
  code  T-1  T-2
0   DE   27   28
1   GT   21   16
2   KT   23   23
3   SZ   18   24
4   NJ   17    7
5   DC   13   18
```

Comment: Your method works. The method 2 i propose before is similar to yours. More verbose but without any warning message.

Comment: Yes your answer is quite good as well as you mentioned in comments mine don't require other dependencies like numpy. And mine is partially vectorized but i itterated for columns which isn't vectorized as number of columns will be limited so performance wise it is almost equal to fully vectorized code. Your solution is a better version of the existing solutions so great job u worked on them glad my solution did help.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have months in order per group of 3 columns, you can use:

```
import numpy as np

group = np.arange(len(df.columns)-1)//3+1

(df.set_index('code')
   .groupby(group, axis=1) 
   .sum()
   .add_prefix('T-')
)
```

If you want to extract the trimester from the column names of potentially unsorted columns (e.g., `M-4`->`T-2`):

```
group = (df.columns[1:].str[2:].astype(int)-1)%3+1

(df.set_index('code')
   .groupby(group, axis=1) 
   .sum()
   .add_prefix('T-')
)
```

output:

```
      T-1  T-2  T-3
code               
DE      8    9   10
GT      9    4    8
KT     10   10    3
SZ      5   11    2
NJ     13    3    1
DC      4    9    0
```

Comment: You propose to play with columns labels. That's a good idea. You didn't considered that i want to sum only "full" trimester. T-3 column should not be created.